# Cannot go to parent directory

Tags: php, file, function, filesystems

I'm encountering a very weird issue.

Normally when I want to go up a folder I use '../' to indicate that the file that I want to open is in a parent directory.

Now I have the following files:

**some-file.phtml**

```
..
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    <?php include 'app/views/html/garbage/test.phtml';?>,
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "bSort": false
    });
    new FixedHeader(table)
    $('div#content_body').children().eq(3).css({'top': '200px', 'position': 'static'})
} );
</script>
```

**test.phtml**

```
Hi2
```

**garbage/test.phtml**

```
Hi
```

- app/views/html/garbage/some-file.phtml
- app/views/html/garbage/test.phtml
- app/views/html/test.phtml

Everytime I use `<?php include 'test.phtml';?>,`

The result is: `Hi,`

But whenever I turn `<?php include 'test.phtml';?>,` into `<?php include '../test.phtml';?>,`

I get the following error:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include(../test.phtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>FOLDERS\app\views\html\garbage\some-file.phtml</b> on line <b>335</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include(): Failed opening '../test.phtml' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in <b>FOLDERS\app\views\html\garbage\some-file.phtml</b> on line <b>335</b><br />
,
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "bSort": false
    });
    new FixedHeader(table)
    $('div#content_body').children().eq(3).css({'top': '200px', 'position': 'static'})
} );
```

It may well be a very basic issue, but I cannot seem to understand what is going wrong.

**Additional info:**

- Using windows
- Using xampp

Comment: What does `var_dump( file_exists('../test.phtml') );` output?

Comment: check your rights in the folder. Maybe you have a bad path, it must be relative to your php file which call the include

Comment: @AmalMurali output = bool(false)

Comment: @Lazykiddy: Check your filepath and make sure it's correct. Hint: filenames and paths are usually case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks guys. This indeed was very basic.

Comment: @Lazykiddy: No worries. Glad to know you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your are still in the root of your `server`/`localhost`/`project path`

```
<?php include '../test.phtml';?>,
```

refers to one step back from your root!

if you have

```
http://localhost/test/here you are
```

you actually refer to

```
http://localhost
```

Comment: My root was in the folder public_html, so I had to use `../app/views/html/test.phtml` instead. Thank you!